# Valor Incorrecto al leer un comboBox

Tags: c#

Estoy extrañado por una cosa. Cargo un comboBox

```
var dtPlantilla = new DataTable();
dtPlantilla = objPlantilla.ObtenerListadoPlantilla(Raiz);
dtPlantilla.Rows.Add(new object[] { 0, "- Seleccione -" });
idPlantilla.DataSource = dtPlantilla;
idPlantilla.ValueMember = "idPlantilla";
idPlantilla.DisplayMember = "url".ToString().Trim();
idPlantilla.SelectedValue = 0;
```

Luego lo que quiero hacer es que, al seleccionar un elemento, me ponga el texto de esa opción de comboBox en un textBox pero, no se por que, me saca por el combo el último elemento que seleccioné, no el que acabo de seleccionar. es decir, hago lo siguiente:

```
Plantilla.Text = idPlantilla.SelectedText.ToString();
```

Pero me saca el último valor que seleccioné anteriormente, en vez de el que se acaba de seleccionar. El caso, es que si lo que quiero sacar es el selectedValue, si me saca el correcto, pero con .SelectedText o con .Text me saca el último.

¿A que es esto debido?

Gracias

Mi función es la siguiente:

```
public DataTable ObtenerListadoPlantilla(Int16 idRaiz)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString);

            string procedimiento = "OBTENER_LISTADO_PLANTILLA_RAIZ_APP";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                {
                    var w = cmd;
                    w.Connection = cn;
                    w.CommandText = procedimiento;
                    w.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    w.Parameters.Add("@i_idRaiz", SqlDbType.SmallInt, 9).Value = idRaiz;
                    w.Parameters["@i_idRaiz"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                    da.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                da = null;
                dt = null;
                cn.Close();
                cn = null;
                cmd = null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Por el orden de como se ejecutan los eventos, prueba a usar el objeto que envía el evento que es un combobox(tendras que combertirlo) y obten de el selectedText

Comment: No te entiendo, perdona.

Comment: Lo que quiere decir que el object de nombre sender  es el combobox asi que lo puedes transformar en un combobox y coger el selectedText. Ya que en algunos eventos este evento ya experimentado el cambio y la idPlantilla por ejemplo aún no .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es que el selectedText no funciona como tú crees. Se refiere a la selección del texto (como cuando seleccionas un texto para copiar/pegar)

Además en la [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), dice claramente

> Sin embargo, si intenta obtener el SelectedText valor en un
> SelectedIndexChanged controlador de eventos o SelectedValueChanged ,
> la propiedad devuelve una cadena vacía. Esto se debe a que, en el
> momento de estos eventos, se ha borrado el valor anterior SelectedText
> y el nuevo valor aún no se ha establecido. Para recuperar el valor
> actual en un SelectedIndexChanged controlador de eventos o
> SelectedValueChanged , use la SelectedItem propiedad en su lugar.

Es decir:

```
textBox1.Text = ((DataRowView)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[1].ToString();
```

Que sería mucho más sencillo si usara clases y binding como te señalamos en un comentario de una publicación anterior

Answer (score 0):

hice una adaptación para poderlo probar y el resultado es que funcióna el código aparentemente usando él .Text. Para la prueba he usado Windows Forms porque no indicaste que usabas.
El código que he usado:

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var dtPlantilla = new DataTable();
        dtPlantilla.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("idPlantilla"));
        dtPlantilla.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Text"));
        dtPlantilla.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Prueba tres" });
        dtPlantilla.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Prueba uno" });
        dtPlantilla.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Prueba dos" });
        dtPlantilla.Rows.Add(new object[] { 0, "- Seleccione -" });
        idPlantilla.DataSource = dtPlantilla;
        idPlantilla.ValueMember = dtPlantilla.Columns[0].ColumnName;
        idPlantilla.DisplayMember = dtPlantilla.Columns[1].ColumnName;//Importante ha de ser igual el nombre de la columna que quieres pasar para que funcione
        
        idPlantilla.SelectedValue = 0;


    }

    private void idPlantilla_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Plantilla.Text = idPlantilla.Text.ToString();
    }
```

El resultado es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que parece que el problema no se ve en el código que mandaste en caso, por lo que interesaría que pasaras la función de objPlantilla.ObtenerListadoPlantilla(Raiz);

Comment: He editado mi pregunta original para que veas la función

Comment: Vale al ser una stored procedure de la base de datos es difícil replicarlo a primera vista  parece que no hay ningún problema, pero para asegurar puedes usar lo siguiente al asignar el valueMember y el displayMember. I comprobar cual función usas para hacer el trigger, ya que en algunas aún no ha canviado el texto cuando se disparan.  idPlantilla.ValueMember = dtPlantilla.Columns[0].ColumnName; idPlantilla.DisplayMember = dtPlantilla.Columns[1].ColumnName;

Comment: Viendo lo que tenemos solo falta ver cuál función usas para hacer el trigger en el combobox

Answer (score 0):

Por el orden de como se ejecutan los eventos, prueba a usar el objeto que envía el evento que es un combobox(tendras que combertirlo) y obten de el selectedText

Por ejemplo:

```
 private void idPlantilla_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    
        ComboBox senderComboBox = (ComboBox) sender;
      
        Plantilla.Text = senderComboBox.SelectedText;
     
    }
```

Para obtener más información sobre el manejo de eventos, consulte controlar y provocar eventos.

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/events/